# Flutter app crashes when recording video with front camera flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, camera, crash, video-recording

I am using the latest version of camera plugin in my app for recording videos. The recording works perfect on Android (front and back camera), but on iOS I am facing app crash after I start video recording using front (selfie) camera (with back camera it works perfect).

Important to mention is that the same happens in both, debug and release mode.

I am getting this as output in terminal:

```
2021-07-25 16:05:11.817638+0200 Runner[24063:4564758] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[AVCaptureAudioDataOutput setSampleBufferDelegate:queue:] NULL queue passed'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x18d8ea754 0x1a23b17a8 0x1a7845470 0x1049ef31c 0x1049ec704 0x1049f1d2c 0x1049f0a24 0x106e4c0b4 0x106e4dde0 0x106e55ef0 0x106e56d14 0x106e63a50 0x1d944e7a4 0x1d945574c)
libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[AVCaptureAudioDataOutput setSampleBufferDelegate:queue:] NULL queue passed'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try running the App in release mode using this command in the Terminal:

```
flutter run --release
```

Maybe this is just a problem with the debug build.

Comment: My fault, forgot to mention it in the question... It happens even in release mode after I download the app with Testflight

Comment: @jux_97 maybe add it to your Question so people can help you better : )

Comment: will add it. Thanks